# InvalidateQueries are executed at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, request, tanstackreact-query

```
 const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["click"], () =>
        makeRequest.get("/example/1234").then((res) => {
          return res.data;
        })
      );
    
    const Path = async (postId, cardNickNameId) => {
        const promise = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await makeRequest.post("/elpmaxe", {
              postId: postId,
              cardNickNameId: cardNickNameId,
            });
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(["click"]); //<------ BAD!
            console.log(res);
            return Promise.resolve(res.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return Promise.reject(error.res.data);
          }
        };
        const success = PromisseSucess("Assinando com sucesso!").success;
        //prettier-ignore
        const pending = PromisseLoading("Subscribing you to the best plan.").pending;
        //prettier-ignore
        const error = PromisseError("You need add a payment method or choose a card!").error;
    
        const toastOptions = {
          success,
          pending,
          error,
        };
    
        toast.promise(promise, toastOptions);
      };
```

When he makes the GET request, he searches for my database data, this data is usually updated a lot, so I always need to invalidate the queries to have fresh data. If I put the invalidation that way it runs too fast and doesn't work, the setTimeout worked fine but it's a terrible bad practice, I don't want to use it.
the goal is that when I use queryClient.invalidateQueries(["click"]) it will update the data and get it to me with GET

Comment: please extend your question. it is not clear what you want to achieve or how `Path` and `useQuery` relates to each other

Comment: the goal is that when I use queryClient.invalidateQueries(["click"]) it will update the data and get it to me with GET

Comment: Any some idea ?